# z-index doesn't work correctly with all layer

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I want to do simple animation in HTML + CSS. Somethink like progressbar.
I have backgroung - #mid.
I have form for "bar" - #kingIcon
I have content "bar" - #kingIconBack
kingIcon and mid works correctly. kingIcon is on mid, with corrent opacity. But content bar - kingIconBack cover all

I tried change position.

```
CSS 
#mid{
    width: 60%;
    background-color: rgb(59, 194, 153);
    float: left;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}


#kingIcon{
    margin-top: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;

}

#kingIconBack{
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;

}


HTML

<div id="mid">
          <div id="kingIcon"><img src="krolPrzezroczysty.png" width="100%"  alt="kingIcon">
                    <div id="kingIconBack"><img src="gradient.png" width="141.2%"  > </div>
                  </div>


        </div>
```

content bar - kingIconBack cover all

Comment: Is it covering all of the page, or all of its parent? Try defining a width in your kingIconBack.

Comment: All of the page.
With width too.

Comment: You are defining a width of 141% in your image for kingIconBack. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, becouse i put layers by it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that `kingIconBack` can't be a child of `kingIcon`.

Thanks for all comments!